# PYTHON: Trouble Understanding this Fibonacci Code

Tags: python, fibonacci

I understand how Fibonacci works, its just this code is driving me crazy. I might be going through it wrong

```
def fib1(n):
  if n == 1 or n == 2:
    return 1 
  return fib1(n-1) + fib1(n-2)


for i in range(1,10):
  print(fib1(i))

output = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

Okay, so starting with 1 it returns 1 then 2 returns 1 too, But then 3 gets sent to fib1(n-1) + (n-2) and it returns 2?, isnt (3-1)+(3-2) == 3? I might be formatting it wrong but please explain how it happens

Comment: It isn't `(2) + (1)` it's `fib(2) + fib(1)`.  What is `fib(1)`?  What is `fib(2)`?

Comment: It's not `(n-1) + (n-2)`. It's `fib1(n-1) + fib1(n-2)`.

Comment: This is called _recursion_. But, unfortunately, in order to understand recursion you must first understand recursion...

Comment: When `n==3`, it _doesn't_ return `(3-1)+(3-2)` it returns  `fib1(3-1) + fib1(3-2)` == `fib1(2) + fib1(1)` which is 1+1 == 2

Answer (score 0):

So it's not like returning (3-1)+(3-2), it's making a [recursive call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), calling itself, by doing fib1(3-1) + fib1(3-2), which breaks down to be fib1(2) + fib1(1)  which returns 1+1

We can work it out by walking through fib1(4):

fibl1(4) --> fibl(4-1) + fibl(4-2)

fib1(4) -- > fibl(3) + fibl1(2)

fibl(4) -- > (fibl(3-1) + fibl(3-2)) + 1 (2 is a base case so it returns 1)

fibl(4) -- > (fibl(2) + fibl(1) ) + 1

fibl(4) -- > (1 + 1) + 1

fibl(4) -- > 3